# classes_1.Person is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am using a TypeScript project I made by myself, but I am having some issues with imports and exports.

I have a folder `classes` with each class having it's specific file that exports the class. I then have a file `index.ts`, which imports all the classes and exports them from one file for easier use in code.

Person.ts:

```
class Person {}

export default Person
```

index.ts:

```
import Person from "./Person"

export { Person }
```

app.ts:

```
import { Person } from "@classes

const person = new Person()
```

The issue is that the above code does not work and fires an error `classes_1.Person is not a constructor`

I am using alias paths configured in `tsconfig.json` as so:

```
"paths": {
    "@classes": ["classes"],
    "@interfaces": ["interfaces"],
    "@enums": ["enums"],
    "@const": ["const"]
}
```

I am not using the format that is shown in TS docs: `"@classes/*": ["classes/*"]` as that is not ideal for my use case.

I compile the code with `npx tsc && npx tsc-alias`

If I look into the transpiled .js code, the VSCode understands all imports, but if I launch the app with `node ./dist/app.js`, it does not work.

Comment: you're missing a closing `"` here `import Person from "./Person`

Comment: fixed, i have it right in code, i just cant copy properly

Comment: Does it work without the alias ? `import { Person } from "./classes"`

Comment: @Jean-Alphonse it does not, interesting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a circular dependency between the files. In `index.ts` I was importing multiple classes, which were dependent on each other in some way. I fixed it by moving the depending class to the top, so the import statement imports that class first.